# Execute a scheduled task on one (and only one) domain controller

Tags: active-directory, powershell, windows-server-2016, scheduled-task

I am setting up an Active Directory domain. It includes some Linux servers that use sssd to access the users and groups of the domain.

Because the users and groups need a UID and GID for that (I don't want to use the `ldap_id_mapping` option of sssd), I've prepared powershell scripts to run whenever a user or group is added. They search for the highest assigned UID (or GID) and assign the next one to the new user/group.

The scripts are triggered as a task for the appropriate EventIDs (e.g. 4720 for user created).

This all seems to work pretty well. However, because I have at least two domain controllers, and want to provide this functionality even when one is down, I need to add the task on both. But this means that my script runs twice, and possibly even worse, concurrently. I would prefer not having to write some locking mechanism, though.

Is there a way to make sure a task runs on only one domain controller? I couldn't find an option in the task scheduler.

Comment: Have the script run based on the results of a test-connection, if both are available, have it randomly choose one of the two, if only one is available, have it run on the responding DC.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the task on only one domain controller, perhaps you could run the task on every domain controller, but change your Powershell script so that the script itself only targets only *one* domain controller -- perhaps make it so the PowerShell script always targets the domain controller with the PDCe FSMO role.

I'm not sure what cmdlets (if any) you're using in your script, but if using Set-ADUser from the ActiveDirectory Module, you can easily target the cmdlet with the "-Server" parameter.

> I would prefer not having to write some locking mechanism, though.

AD is multi-master, it has a conflict resolution process and can automatically resolve conflicts when writes happen on the same object.  I'm fairly certain you don't need to worry about breaking Active Directory with some duplicated attribute updates.

---

It also seems to me that the most logical means of accomplishing what you're trying to do is to just automate (script) the user creation process such that the UID/GID is assigned at the time of user creation and not triggered by an event in a security log.